# How to build a browser extension that modifies a website's dynamic DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, plugins, browser, google-chrome-extension

We need to create an extension that inserts our own DOM elements in another website which changes dynamically. We have looked at various tutorials (examples below) that don't explain clearly how to do this.

- https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devguide.html
- http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2009/09/how-to-build-a-twitter-extension-for-chrome/

However, there are very good examples of others that have done this:

- Buffer:  They have inserted there own 'Buffer' elements in Twitter (and Facebook)
- Klout:  They have inserted there own 'Klout' elements in Twitter (and Facebook)

Focusing on Buffer, they have added their own 'Buffer' element to the Tweet action options row.  Even, when one 'pages down' in Twitter, the 'older' Tweets get the 'Buffer' button added dynamically.

So there are two questions:

1. Can anyone summarize how to do what Buffer does or point to examples of how this can be done?
2. Also, generally speaking, what is the scope of things that can or cannot be done in an browser extension (event handling, listening, modifying an external webpage, etc)?

We are currently focusing on Chrome and FireFox.

Any and all help is appreciated in advance.

Thanks!

Comment: Watch the DOM with a `MutationObserver` and process mutation events as desired

Comment: Thank you for the great reference.  Does the MO get triggered when a URL is first visited?  In other words, when you go to a new URL, will the MO return new contents of the URL?  In the context of an 'extension' and it's associated content script, it is not clear at what point the content script (which contains the MO code) will be triggered.  Will the MutationObserver return the new DOM (of the new URL) or do we have to read that DOM on our own separately the first time the page get's loaded?

Comment: Depends on when you attach the MO. Personally, Id recommend you wait for contentloaded or the load event to be fired before attaching it and do a full check on the page load